# Update specific part of all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying update a specific part of all rows with SQL. Below an example:

```
**table **

788745.ext
998520.ext
447789.ext
174664.ext
788012.ext
```

I want to replace the ".ext" part with ".jpg".

Comment: Is that all you want to do, replace .ext with .jpg? Or are there other cases that need handled?

Comment: @Error_2646 just replace all .ext for .jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
update names
    set name = concat(substring_index(name, '.', 1), '.jpg')
    where name like '%.ext';
```

This assumes that there is only one `.` in the name.

If you *know* that `.ext` does not appear anywhere else in the name, you can use `replace()`:

```
update names
    set name = replace(name, '.ext', '.jpg')
    where name like '%.ext';
```

Or you can replace the last three characters using the `insert()` function:

```
update names
    set name = insert(name, length(name) - 2, 3, 'jpg')
    where name like '%.ext';
```

Comment: Replacing the last three characters (if they are "ext") is more efficient.

Comment: Wouldn't this not work for 788.745.ext?

Comment: @Error_2646 Read carefully, he already said that *This assumes that there is only one . in the name*.

Comment: @RacilHilan doh, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the extension `ext` only appears at the end of each string, it is more efficient to simply replace the last three characters:

```
UPDATE names
SET name = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(name, 1, LENGTH(name) - 3), 'jpg')
WHERE SUBSTRING(name, -3) = 'ext';
```